# Excel VBA - Create rows for each updated value in DDE link cell

Tags: excel, vba, dde

Lets say cell A1 has a DDE link, "=dde(realtime_stock_price".  How can I send the value to a new row of a column everytime it updates?  The Change() function doesnt work because its not the user doing the change.  I tried the Calculate() function but not too sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

The formula "=dde()" isn't something I am familiar with. However you could just make your own dde function which calls your event code...

```
Public Function dde2(ByVal app as string,ByVal topic as string,ByVal item as string) as variant
    with Application
        channelNumber = .DDEInitiate(app,topic) 
        dde2 = .DDERequest(channelNumber, "Topics")
        .DDETerminate(channelNumber)
    end with
    on error resume next   'incase macro doesn't exist
        Application.run "dde2_postExec", dde2
    on error goto 0
End Function

Sub dde2_postExec(ByVal message as string)
    'do stuff...
end sub
```

#### Edit

According to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1100579/681916) the string passed to `=DDE()` is `"Service|Topic!Item"`. Or in our case: `"App|Topic!Item"` which can be extracted from the string easily. However do note that [`DDE()` is NOT a native function of excel](https://superuser.com/a/1100602/681916). So it is unlikely we will be able to know how `DDE()` is working to make a clean solution.

#### Edit2

Given your comment, say DDE is streaming `"12...13...14..."` and you want to output `B1 = 12`, `B2=13` and `B3=14`. Your code would be something like this [untested]:

```
Sub dde2_postExec(ByVal message as string)
    dim v as variant: v=split(message,"...")
    for i = 1 to ubound(v)-1
        range("B" & i).value = v(i)
    next
end sub
```

However do note that this may not work if called as a formula. The VBA runtime is designed such that when forumla's are evaluated they cannot write values to cells in the sheet, other than the cell that called them. For this reason you may be forced into hooking into worksheet events instead of using the formula's calculate event.

Comment: Could you clarify what your code is doing?  To restate, Lets say the DDE cell is streaming: "12...13...14...".  I want a column with rows that will append with the new outputs"  B1 = 12, B2 = 13, B3 = 14 and so on.  Thanks

Comment: Sure. See Edit2.

Comment: instead of message as String, can we do...number as Val?

Comment: You can do whatever you like Excel passes the value through as a variant, so as long as it has the desired effect when passing the function across, sure you can do it. Now whether it would work how you intend it, I'm not sure. That depends on your code.